# Removing the content of a directory recursively

Tags: directory

I want to delete the content of a folder without deleting a folder: all files and all sub folders with sub files. This doesn't delete anything

```
sudo rm -rf /folder1/*
```

Why not? How to get it to work?

Comment: What do you mean *This doesn't delete anything*? Does it give any error?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, guess what that means.

Comment: I'm sensing an XY-problem here. Why do you want this? What do you *actually* trying to achieve? Why not just delete the folder and then create an empty one with the same name?

Comment: Can the user running the command (before sudo), list the directory?

Answer (score 2):

Is this `folder1` really directly in root `/`? You must either use relative or absolute path:

```
sudo rm -rf folder1/*
sudo rm -rf /full/path/to/folder1/*
```

Then you must remember that the wildcard is handled *before* `sudo`. If the user doesn't have permission to read contents of `folder1`, the wildcard returns nothing. You can test that with

```
sudo echo folder1/*
```

In that case you may

```
sudo bash
rm -rf folder1/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You said sudo **"rm -rf /folder1/*"** is not working for you
It happens if you have thousands of file in a directory either it will be too long to process or it will say *argument list too long* in this cases you can try below command

first cd to the directory you want files to be deleted **cd /folder/**

/bin/ls -A | xargs rm -rf

That will remove all files and directories, even the hidden ones that begin with a dot, except the special . and .. directories. You don't want to remove . and .. (they are the current and parent directories, respectively).